# Execute Scalar can't return the existing row

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have faced a problem regarding **mark duplicate data**. In my project, the record which already exists can't be recorded twice. I have followed multiple posts of stackoverflow and come to know that I have to use **executescalar** to do that.. I have used executescalar but it can't handle the existing data. Would you please help me to sort it out.

Here is my part of code:

```
    {

        appointmentdate = dtappointmentdate.Value;
        today = DateTime.Now;
        String prob = txtproblemdefination.Text;
        String rec = "";
        if (appointmentdate < today)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Correct Date.");
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand check_User_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM appointmentTable WHERE PatientName = '" + patientname + "'And (DoctorName = '" + docname + "'And AppointmentDateSet = '" + appointmentdate + "')", sqlCon);
            check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patname", patientname);
            check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docname", docname);
            check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appointmentdate", appointmentdate);
            if (sqlCon.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
            }
            int UserExist = (Int32)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();

            if (UserExist > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You can't make appointment twice a day. ");
            }

            else
            {
                SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into appointmentTable(PatientName,DoctorName,ClinicLocation,AppointmentDateSet,Problem,Recommendation) values(@docname, @patname, @doclocation, @appointmentdate,@prob,@rec)");
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patname", patientname);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docname", docname);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doclocation", doclocation);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appointmentdate", appointmentdate);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prob", prob);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rec", rec);
                int row = objdbaccess.executeQuery(insertCommand);
                if (row == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Appointment is Successfully Done.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error!Please try again later.");
                }
                sqlCon.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: You are using parameterized queries, which is nice, but in the first query, you concate variables and use parameters

Comment: You're not using the command parameters in the SELECT query an also checking a perfect equivalence using a `DateTime` is improbable. What data type is `AppointmentDateSet`? You should use `Parameters.Add()`, specifying a matching data type.

Comment: @Jimi..How can I use the command parameters in the select query..Would you please help me ?

Comment: Execute Scalar has only one column.  You must use ExecuteNonQuery which returns an integer.  If the Integer value is zero then row already exists.  So then you need to create an UpdateCommand which will update the existing row.

Comment: @jdweng int UserExist = (Int32)check_User_Name.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (UserExist == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You can't make appointment twice a day. ");
                }

Comment: The same way you used them in the INSERT query. See also what jdweng wrote: you're missing that too. There could also be something to say about the way you're handling the connection object...

Comment: The appointments have to be able to handle time of day.  Do you want all your appoints to last an entire day?  You have a primary key in the table that allows only one value with the same key.  You only have an appointment date column which does not allow two appoints with same date.  So the appointment needs both a Time and a Date to be unique which will allow two appointments in one day.

Comment: OT when you show the messagebox, you don't close the connection - connections in .Net are meant to be closed as soon as possible, to let the internal connection pooling do its job

Comment: What exactly is the date that is stored - just a date or including a time? What datatype is the column?

Comment: jdweng, Now I can understand..Thanks a lot..Should I use only date then instead of DateTIme ?

Comment: @jdweng ExecuteScalar is the perfect choice for returning the single column/single row result of a Count(*)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing its the datetime..It was my fault..Thanks a lot for helping me..Thanks a lot..

Comment: You guys are awesome..Thanks for helping me..Thanks a lot..I have solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code to:

I am assuming appointmentdate is of type `DateTime` if not you can choose the correct type from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dbtype?view=netframework-4.8)

```
using(var check_User_Name= SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM appointmentTable WHERE PatientName = @patname And DoctorName = @docname And AppointmentDateSet = @appointmentdate )", sqlCon)
{

    check_User_Name.Parameters.Add("@patname", DbType.String).Value = patientname;
    check_User_Name.Parameters.Add("@docname", DbType.String).Value = docname;
    check_User_Name.Parameters.Add("@appointmentdate", DbType.DateTime).Value = appointmentdate;        
    con.Open();
    int UserExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();
    // Followed by your code
}
```

Comment: I think i will be better to move this piece of code to Data access class maybe